# how to replace only parenthesized expression javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider

```
myString = "Updated first_name, email, last_name"
```

I would like to add a bit of grammer and i tried

```
myString.replace(/(,\s)[\sa-zA-Z_0-9]+$/," and ")
```

But i get

```
"Updated first_name, email and "
```

Unfortunatley the regex also replaces the 'last_name' because it was used to find the offending `', '`
I thought the parenthesis would make it only replace the `', '` 
How do i achieve my objective?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: `myString.replace(/,\s(\w*)$/," and $1")`

Comment: or even you can use `lastIndexOf`

Comment: Thank you all, reall clean and consice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of answers already but here are my two cents too:

```
var myString = "Updated first_name, email, last_name";

var t= myString.replace(/,\s([\sa-zA-Z_0-9]+)$/," and $1");
alert(t);
```

You can [play with the fidlle here](https://jsfiddle.net/v9yfwL89/)

Answer (score 0):

`String.replace` replaces the matching substring / regexp with a new substring.

In your code, the match includes everithing from the last `','` till the end, so that's what gets replaced.

You can change your regexp to: `(,(?!(.)*,))` and it should work.

```js
alert('Updated first_name, email, last_name'.replace(/(,(?!(.)*,))/, ' and'))
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2btzufbx/)

```
myString.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, ' and')
```

This will find any commas that are not followed by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
var myString = "Updated first_name, email, last_name" ;
myString=myString.replace(/,(?=[^,]*$)/, 'and')
alert(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `replace` param to

```
myString.replace(/, *([\w]+)$/, " and $1")
```